# Node-red set get http request parameters

Tags: node-red

With Node-Red, I'm trying to set the right parameters for http request, but I'm not able to do it.

[image: the block used]

[image: Function code]

[image: Http request setting]

The query with curl is this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"auth_key":"xf79rra", "payload":null}' https://retepaiot.it/sensordata/0018b1213
```

and it works.

I think I've made somethings wrong passing auth_key and payload (they are not URL parameters).
I use the function to prepare the message:

```
msg.headers = {    
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };


msg.payload = {auth_key:"xf7xxxx9rra", 
    payload:null};
return msg;
```

and http request for URL:

```
https://retepaiot.it/sensordata/001xxxx1213
```

the returned message is:

```
{ "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```

Comment: What do you get as the response when you run the `curl` command, is it a JSON string? The error is about processing the reply, not what you are sending.

Comment: the return is statusCode: 400 (Bad request)

Comment: Which means the error is accurate, because "statusCode: 400 (Bad request" is not JSON

Comment: Yes, that's right. The question is how to fill the request on node-red.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Return type" at the bottom of the node config, you have explicitly asked for a JSON object

Comment: The reply to the request is json. Anyway, using other options the result does not change.

Comment: That's not what you said in the comments on the question. I explicitly asked what the return from the working `curl` command was.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.
Curl returns the requested data.
This is one example:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 310310,
            "time": "2020-02-23T12:27:07",
            "device_eui": "0018b22000001213",
            "rssi": -115,
            "station": "00800000a00047da",
            "data": "428001107fe200000000",
            "frequenza": "868500000",
            "modulazione": "868500000",
            "lat": 44.812036,
            "lon": 10.313763
        }
    ],
    "message": "OK"
}

Comment: Edit the question to include that output. I also suggest you use something like https://hookbin.com/ to compare what is actually sent from both `curl` and `node-red`

Comment: My opinion is that using the node-red Http request, the payload is not added if the GET command is used. Is removed. Get does not expect data in the body.
Here are some related consideration.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Curl doesn't do that. The -d flag force the data in the body.

The problem is that the called server is out of my domain, I cannot change it, and it requires the body for authorization. 

Conclusion: I don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: OK, this looks like a bug. Please raise one [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues). Make sure you fill in the template properly and you can include a link to this question. I have a quick and dirty fix but it will need to be reviewed by the project

Answer (score 0):

The method GET, called from http request, doesn't manage the payload (body on http). Simply it ignores it. 
This conforms to the protocol, so it isn't a bug (see the comments).

The REST server, which I'm calling, seems not to be compliant with the GET method.

For now, I've modified the source code of node [www request](https://github.com/spawnrider/node-red-contrib-http-request). Next, I'll develop my own node.

It might be useful the modification of http request code, to support even servers not fully compliant.

Comment: NO! do not build your own node, open the issue as I requested and we can get the core node fixed. Adding yet another node to the list of available nodes is WRONG thing to do.

Comment: Ok, I'll open a bug, even if I think it's not really a bug.